# PostgreSQL - How do I extract a string that is before a comma OR between a delimiter/comma, but only where the value after the comma is greater than 0

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv

I have a column of data that looks like this:

```
52,0:58,1094.00
52,227.00
58,383:105,0
58,0:112,0:64,85.00
58,1376:112,0:105,0:107,0
57,2858.00
52,0:58,98
57,0:106,3317.00
```

I need to extract every number that is either before a **comma ","** OR between a **colon ":"** AND **comma ","** ONLY where the value after the **comma ","** is greater than 0.

Using the data above, I want to get:

```
58
52
58
64
58
57
58
106
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I think you should fix your data model.  Storing such values in strings is a really bad idea.  Although possible in SQL, it is not really the right tool for this.

Comment: I agree with you. Unfortunately I have no other choice than to use this current data model. I am interested to see if anyone has a solution for this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
select split_part(s.v, ',', 1)::numeric res
from mytable t
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.vals, ':') as s(v)
where split_part(s.v, ',', 2)::numeric > 0
```

The query uses `regexp_split_to_table()` to split the strings on the `':'` separator into new rows, that contains values like `'52,0'` or `'58,1094.00'`. Then, we use `split_part()` to extract the two numbers, and use the second one for filtering.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6a97fa340682cec72d637b78b305b44a)**:

```
select split_part(s.v, ',', 1) res
from mytable t
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.vals, ':') as s(v)
where split_part(s.v, ',', 2)::numeric > 0
```

```
| res |
| :-- |
| 58  |
| 52  |
| 58  |
| 64  |
| 58  |
| 57  |
| 58  |
| 106 |
```

Comment: Hi GMB. Thanks for your answer, I think this will work. But I need to modify this query to work with my DB. Could you elaborate on what "s.v" and "t.vals" is in your example?

Comment: The name of my table is "inventory" and the column containing the data is named "inventory.roomdata"

Comment: @Logan4200: just replace `mytable` with `inventory` and `vals` with `roomdata`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work with my database. Here is the error:                   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 3: cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.roomdata, ':') as...
                                                  ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 95

Comment: @Logan4200: which version of Postgres are you using? `select version();` can tell you.

Comment: Oh I see. Looks like the application I have to use has an older version - PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit.

Comment: @Logan4200: that's sooo old.. relased in 2012 and out of maintenance since 2017. You should really consider upgrading. Major things happened in Postgres since then.